# ggvis slider is squashed

Tags: r, ggvis

I am using R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16) from RStudio Version 0.98.1103.
The platform is platform i386-w64-mingw32.  I am using Windows Vista Version 6. This code

```
require(ggvis)
require(dplyr)

# ggvis use of a slider

mtcars %>% 
    ggvis(~wt, ~mpg, size := input_slider(10, 100), 
                opacity := input_slider(0,1) ) %>% 
    layer_points()
```

works, but the slider is squashed on the left of the plot and therefore difficult to use.  How can I overcome this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the CRAN version of `ggvis`.

Try:

```
# install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("hadley/lazyeval", build_vignettes = FALSE)
devtools::install_github("hadley/dplyr", build_vignettes = FALSE)
devtools::install_github("rstudio/ggvis", build_vignettes = FALSE)

library(ggvis)

mtcars %>% 
  ggvis(~wt, ~mpg, size := input_slider(10, 100), 
        opacity := input_slider(0,1) ) %>% 
  layer_points()
```

Comment: Thank you.  Everything that I have tried now works except the following code that fails to produce the confidence interval:

Comment: Here is the code   mtcars %>% ggvis(~wt, ~mpg) %>%
    layer_smooths(se = input_checkbox(label = "Confidence interval"))

Comment: @JulianStander Since you are using the code from ggvis' documentation there is no error on your side. It's probably a bug, which I have reported over at [GitHub](https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis/issues/401). `ggivs` is not being actively developed right now, but I'd expect development to continue later this year, after hadley finished working on some other stuff.